# copy trimmed range (of selection) from workbook to a new one

Tags: excel, vba

the below code is used to copy a trimmed range (of selection) from workbook to a new created one. 
**Meaning,** If I select any cell(s) on the row, then it create a `Range("A:B,D:E,H:H,J:K")` of the same row(s) and union with the header.
at this point, it works as it should.
****But**, I need to adapt and add a condition:**
if cell `"L*"` (on source workbook) has a value on the same row then it replace the corresponding `"A*"` on the destination workbook.
and if cell `"L*"` (on source workbook) on the same row is blank then my original code as it is.
in advance , greatly thanks for your help.

```
Sub export_trimmed_Selection()

   Const headerRow As Long = 2

   Dim swb As Workbook, sh As Worksheet
   Dim uRng As Range, rng As Range, TrimmedRange As Range, selc As Range

   Set swb = ThisWorkbook              'Source Workbook
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
     Set selc = Intersect(sh.UsedRange, Selection.EntireRow.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))

   If Not uRng Is Nothing Then
      Set rng = Union(selc, uRng)
    Else
      Set rng = selc
   End If

   Dim srg As Range, dwb As Workbook, drg As Range, rr As Range
   
   Set TrimmedRange = Intersect(rng, sh.UsedRange)
    Set srg = Intersect(TrimmedRange.EntireRow, sh.Range("A:B,D:E,H:H,J:K"))
     Set dwb = Workbooks.Add              'Destination Workbook
      Set drg = dwb.Sheets(1).Range("A1")

     For Each rr In srg.Areas
       If srg Is Nothing Then
          Set srg = Union(rr, rr.EntireColumn.Rows(headerRow))
        Else
          Set srg = Union(srg, rr, rr.EntireColumn.Rows(headerRow))
       End If
     Next
    
    srg.Copy
    drg.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
    srg.Copy drg
       
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next way. It copies the discontinuous range, then places the first column from the destination range in an array and processed it based on the discontinuous range rows iteration, using `Offset` of the cells in the last column (at the sheet level range...):

```
Sub export_trimmed_Selection()
   Const headerRow As Long = 2
   Const colsAddress As String = "A:B,D:E,H:H,J:K"

   Dim swb As Workbook, sh As Worksheet
   Dim uRng As Range, rng As Range, TrimmedRange As Range, selc As Range

   Set swb = ThisWorkbook              'Source Workbook
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
     Set selc = Intersect(sh.Range(colsAddress), Selection.EntireRow.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
     
   'If Not uRng Is Nothing Then
   '   Set rng = Union(selc, uRng)
   ' Else
      Set rng = selc
   'End If

   Dim srg As Range, dwb As Workbook, drg As Range, rr As Range
   
   Set TrimmedRange = Intersect(rng, sh.UsedRange)
    Set srg = Intersect(sh.rows(headerRow), sh.Range(colsAddress))

     Set srg = Union(srg, selc)

    Dim shN As Worksheet
    Set dwb = Workbooks.Add              'Destination Workbook
    set shn=dwb.Sheets(1)
    Set drg = shN.Range("A1")
    
    srg.Copy
    drg.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
    srg.Copy drg
 
    Dim j As Long, lastR As Long, arrModif:
    lastR = shN.Range("A" & shN.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    ReDim arrModif(1 To lastR, 1 To 1)
    arrModif = shN.Range("A1:A" & lastR).Value2
    
     For Each rr In srg.rows 'iterate between the discontinuous range rows:
        If rr.cells(1, 2).column = 11 Then ' for the last group of two columns ("JK")
            j = j + 1 'increment each time such a cell has column 11 (K)
            If j > 1 Then 'only skips the header
                If sh.Range(rr.cells(1, 2).Offset(0, 1).address).Value <> "" Then 'compare value in "L:L" using offset addres (on the sheet range)
                    arrModif(j, 1) = sh.Range(rr.cells(1, 2).Offset(0, 1).address).Value2 'change A:A content if no null string in L:L
                End If
            End If
        End If
     Next
     
    'Drop the processed array result at once:
    shN.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrModif), 1).Value2 = arrModif:
    
     MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

Comment: `drg` is not set (I did) , It works. But I found out that you removed the part of `union` the Header with the final range.

Comment: @Waleed It was, but I used a sheet from existing resting workbooks. Missed adapting it. I  rapidly adapted the code to also have a header, **if you select the range to be processed**. Now I am leaving...

Comment: I got `Run-time error '1004': This action won't work on multiple selections` @ this line `srg.Copy` , this error happens even if I selected one cell.

Comment: @Waleed **I suggested you to paste a picture of your data range to be processed**. Because of this fact somebody voted to close your question... You do not even explain **what selection does mean**... For me, in these circumstances, selecting a cell sounds crazy. It may not, if I will be able to read your mind, but this is not an ability I (we) have. Wen I wanted to check the `Offset` property outside the range I selected all columns from "A:A" to "K:K", having the necessary hidden columns in between. So, **what do you select** and **what do you expect to receive after the code run**, please?

Comment: @Waleed I said above **if you select the range to be processed**... Now, you have to explain what you try doing in terms of selection to give me a hint related to **the way o BUILDING the range to be processed** in terms of what the above code does.

Comment: I am sorry for any inconvenience. your answer is accepted

Comment: @Waleed I **do not care about the acceptance**! You should know that... I would like to **exactly** understand of **what you need**! Looking to your comments, if I would say that if you select some cells (even one) on the respective sheet, the code should extract the corresponding range of `Selection.EntireRow` for the mentioned columns, as range to be processed (plus the header...)? Would it be a good understanding? If yes, your way of intersecting the `UsedRange` is not the most appropriate, since even empty cells are visible, IF YOU USED TO HAVE A VALUE AFTER THE LASTCOLUMN, EVEN DELETED...

Comment: @Waleed I adapted the code to behave according to may above explained understanding. Does it do now what you need? I also commented some code lines which are useless. Starting `If Not uRng Is Nothing Then`. If `uRng` is not set in your code, the first conditional code line will never be `True`...

Comment: Ok I will test your new code. **If you wish to understand my need,** then Please try my own code (**I suggested yesterday**) but note the headerRow is on the second row , then select any cell(s) e.g (`A4,D6,F8`) and run my code.

Comment: now I tried your adapted code, Yes it is exactly what I need 

Comment: @Waleed No need to run the code. The only need was "select any cell(s) e.g (`A4,D6,F8`)"... Which I did not find anywhere in your question. For you, it looks logic, but for me it is not exactly logic. Then, I  never test a code **declared as not doing what you want**... I try understanding what you want and design my own version. I do not want to take mistakes considering being acceptable... Of course, when not so clear I make some assumptions. Not always the correct ones...

Comment: @Waleed Did you understand what I tried saying related to using `UsedRange` to extract `selc`? Make some tests before answering. It is good to learn this aspect, I think... Anyhow, I will be able to reply after some time. I need to go out now.